# In my website while logging out should i set code to delete all cookies

Tags: php, html, web

On my website, should I delete all cookies
while logout along with sessions,
and I am not using remember option on my website
and
one more question
should I add session_regenerate_id(true); on every page of my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a logout script which does not have a 'remember me' option, there is no need to delete any cookies. All you need to do is to delete the session.

Use the following code to delete the session:

```
// Unset all of the session variables
$_SESSION = array();
 
// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

There is no need to add session_regenerate_id(true); on every page of your website. But, always add session_start(); in every page.

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: and about phpsessionid  cookie??

Comment: that is also written. You need to add  session_start() in every page, not session_regenerate_id(true).

Comment: i am talking about cookie

Comment: Ok, so when you destroy a session the cookies of the session are also destroyed.

Comment: ok and many people told me that session_regenerate_id(true); is safe to avoid session hijacking

Comment: Oh, I see. You can refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php for more.

Comment: And could you upvote my answer if you find it helpful?

Comment: in the end i just need to destroy the sesssion

Comment: Destroy and unset, check the code I have written in the answer.